# SOAP UI Property Transfer-getting empty response

Tags: soap, groovy, soa

I am new to SOAP UI. I have created a property transfer in SOAP UI where I have to pass a full line of a request. I am getting empty response as [ ]. Instead if i am searching for any argument , I could retrieve the value of that argument.

```
  hotel:HotelSearchAvailabilityRsp

     hotel:HotelSearchResult

         hotel:HotelProperty HotelChain="LQ" HotelCode="*****" HotelLocation="DEN" Name="LA QUINTA" VendorLocationKey="***" HotelTransportation="*" ReserveRequirement="Guarantee" ParticipationLevel="2" Availability="Available"

          hotel:PropertyAddress

             hotel:Address>6801 TOWER RD</hotel:Address>

           </hotel:PropertyAddress>



           <hotel:HotelRating RatingProvider="AAA">

              <hotel:Rating>2</hotel:Rating>

           </hotel:HotelRating>

        </hotel:HotelProperty>
```

In Property Transfer, I have provided below XPATH

//hotel:HotelSearchAvailabilityRsp/hotel:HotelSearchResult/hotel:HotelProperty[1]
but it returns the value as [    ]

But I could get the proper response if I use below xpath

//hotel:HotelSearchAvailabilityRsp/hotel:HotelSearchResult/hotel:HotelProperty[1]/@VendorLocationKey

Could You please help me to retrieve the entire value of hotel:HotelProperty

Comment: Suresh, can you please provide valid response? what value do you need to extract? HotelProperty is a complex element, not a text value. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Rao, I want to extract the complete details which are embedded within the entire HotelProperty  and pass it to next request. the response am getting out of this property transfer is just empty value  as [     ]

Comment: Can you show your screen shot with expected request for next step? By the way, you did not update the question with valid response.